# Error after changing extent+resolution in r

Tags: r, raster, tiff

I have a tiff file called "tiff4" and here is the information of it:

`class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 49, 89, 4361  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent      : 60.64135, 105.1413, 14.99839, 39.49839  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : C:\Users\Halima Usman\Documents\ICIMOD\hkh1.tif 
names       : hkh1`

Now I require an extent which of are of whole numbers and not decimal places. This is what I do to change extent

`ext <- extent(61, 105, 16, 39)
extent(tiff4)<-ext`

But after changing the extent the resolution also changes. I require a resolution of 0.5 degree
`class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 49, 89, 4361  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.494382, 0.4693878  (x, y)
extent      : 61, 105, 16, 39  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : C:\Users\Halima Usman\Documents\ICIMOD\hkh1.tif 
names       : hkh1`

Then I change the resolution back to 0.5 by doing this:

`res(tiff4)=0.5`
But when i plot tiff4, it gives an error

`Error in .plotraster2(x, col = col, maxpixels = maxpixels, add = add,  : 
  no values associated with this RasterLayer`

How can I fix this error or what is the reason behind this error?
(I have seen this question [Can't change raster's extent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45644037/cant-change-rasters-extent), but as a beginner in R I am not getting desired result)

Comment: Dear Halima, before starting coding I suggest you read more about concepts of "resampling" raster data. Of course, when you change the extent, the resolution also changes! 
If you want to change the extent but not resolution, you need to clip your data.

Answer (score 0):

You changed ymin from 14.99 to 16. That is not good. You could get close by doing this

```
ext <- extent(60.5, 105, 15, 39.5)
```

That would "work" because `(105-60.5) / .5 = 89` and `(39.5-15) / .5 = 49`. That is, the number of rows and columns matches the resolution. However, you have now moved the values spatially, and so they are no longer "correct". And the extent does not have whole numbers.

I would suggest you do something like this instead:

```
r <- raster(tiff4)
extent(r) <- c(60, 105, 15, 40)
r <- resample(tiff4, r)
r
```